# OTF Font appears empty in FontForge

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I am trying to open an OTF file to edit it and remove all the characters I do not need (the file is a Korean font, so it is quite large). When I open the file, every character except A-Z a-z is blank. I have tried opening the file on both Linux and Windows and I'm getting the same result. The font is [Noto Sans Korean](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+KR) from Google. I have tried downloading from other sources besides Google, same thing. Is the font restricted in some way that it won't let me edit it?

I searched online and found this [similar post](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/2906), but changing the .bat file's language to Korean and hiding the unused glyphs did not resolve the issue.

How the font appears when I try to open in FontForge:

[image: How the font appears when I try to open in FontForge]

When I select "Encoding->Compact":

[image: When I select "Encoding->Compact"]

Comment: Which version of FontForge? Because that makes quite a difference. Also, you probably want to ask this over on https://typedrawers.com, which is where all the font folks hang out. Also, since noto korean is an open source font, have you asked on their issue tracker?

Comment: The version is the latest release, 20220308. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to [the lovely folks over at typedrawers.com](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/4456/otf-font-appears-empty-in-fontforge):

> I believe you are dealing with a CID-keyed OpenType CFF (.otf) font.
> Check out the CID menu, and select a different CID range. You are probably looking for the Hangul, but there are many other ranges in this font.
> You could also choose the “Flatten” option on that menu, which would be convenient for viewing, but will prevent round-tripping the font in the same format.